# how to use different denpendency in one project with maven?(android)

Tags: android, maven, android-maven-plugin

I use maven to package my app. Now I want integrate leakcanary only in debug version. So I need to add a `<dependency>` node to my pom.xml. But I want to remove it from release version. How Can I do that? I have a solution that a pom.xml for debug version and another pom for release version. Another solution is use shell to modify pom.xml before package. Any better idea?

maven:3.3.9
com.simpligility.maven.plugins:android-maven-plugin:4.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with [Maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html); they can host several POM elements: property values, configurations, dependencies, etc.
You then enable one of more of these profiles with `-P` when running from the command line, or e.g. in Eclipse, with the specific entry in the `Run as...` window.

Here's a brief example:

```xml
    <!-- Dependencies declarations -->
</dependencies>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>extralib</id>
        <properties>
            <!-- specify property values here -->
        </properties>

        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- add dependency decl here -->
        <dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>

<!-- you may have several profiles -->
```

All of the childs of `<profile>` are optional.